# Writing into specific cells in a csv file

Tags: matlab, csv

I need to write a cell array containing tags like:

STARTED: ENDED: STARTED: ENDED: STARTED: ENDED: ...

into specific rows and and columns in a csv file but when I use something like:

```
csvwrite(fName, tag(3), 4,0)
```

it writes each letter in a separate cell and overwrites the existing data (tag(3) is a vector of type cell).

Any help would be appreciated.

This is brief version of the code:

```
data = importdata('samplelog', ' ');


for i=1:length(data)
    % Extracting the tags 
    [start_i, end_i] = regexp(data{i}, '\D+:');
    tag{i} = data{i}(start_i:end_i);
end

fName = 'mem.csv';
fid = fopen(fName, 'w+');

csvwrite(fName, tag(3), 4, 0);
```

where samplelog is something like:

```
START: 2013-05-04 19:13:06.188
ENDED: 2013-05-04 19:22:41.617
START: 2013-05-04 19:25:52.382
ENDED: 2013-05-04 19:35:27.827
.
.
.
```

Comment: have you tried `tag{3}`?

Comment: Yes, the result is the same!

Comment: Can you add a bit more code so that we can run your code directly?

Comment: What does the cell `tag(3)` contain?

Comment: tag(3) contains  'START:' with the datatype cell.

Comment: @Gholi Thanks, make it faster to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

With [cell2csv.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4400-cell-array-to-csv-file-cell2csv-m), you'll just have to call `cell2csv('mem.csv', tag)`, and it will writes the cell array `tag` into the comma separated values text file `mem.csv`.

[cell2csv.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4400-cell-array-to-csv-file-cell2csv-m):

```
function cell2csv(fileName, cellArray, separator, excelYear, decimal)
% Writes cell array content into a *.csv file.
% 
% CELL2CSV(fileName, cellArray, separator, excelYear, decimal)
%
% fileName     = Name of the file to save. [ i.e. 'text.csv' ]
% cellArray    = Name of the Cell Array where the data is in
% separator    = sign separating the values (default = ';')
% excelYear    = depending on the Excel version, the cells are put into
%                quotes before they are written to the file. The separator
%                is set to semicolon (;)
% decimal      = defines the decimal separator (default = '.')
%
%         by Sylvain Fiedler, KA, 2004
% updated by Sylvain Fiedler, Metz, 06
% fixed the logical-bug, Kaiserslautern, 06/2008, S.Fiedler
% added the choice of decimal separator, 11/2010, S.Fiedler

%% Checking für optional Variables
if ~exist('separator', 'var')
    separator = ',';
end

if ~exist('excelYear', 'var')
    excelYear = 1997;
end

if ~exist('decimal', 'var')
    decimal = '.';
end

%% Setting separator for newer excelYears
if excelYear > 2000
    separator = ';';
end

%% Write file
datei = fopen(fileName, 'w');

for z=1:size(cellArray, 1)
    for s=1:size(cellArray, 2)

        var = eval(['cellArray{z,s}']);
        % If zero, then empty cell
        if size(var, 1) == 0
            var = '';
        end
        % If numeric -> String
        if isnumeric(var)
            var = num2str(var);
            % Conversion of decimal separator (4 Europe & South America)
            % http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DecimalSeparator.svg
            if decimal ~= '.'
                var = strrep(var, '.', decimal);
            end
        end
        % If logical -> 'true' or 'false'
        if islogical(var)
            if var == 1
                var = 'TRUE';
            else
                var = 'FALSE';
            end
        end
        % If newer version of Excel -> Quotes 4 Strings
        if excelYear > 2000
            var = ['"' var '"'];
        end

        % OUTPUT value
        fprintf(datei, '%s', var);

        % OUTPUT separator
        if s ~= size(cellArray, 2)
            fprintf(datei, separator);
        end
    end
    if z ~= size(cellArray, 1) % prevent a empty line at EOF
        % OUTPUT newline
        fprintf(datei, '\n');
    end
end
% Closing file
fclose(datei);
% END
```

I must reproduce the license here, sorry:

```
Copyright (c) 2004-2010, Sylvain Fiedler
All rights reserved.

Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without 
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are 
met:

    * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright 
      notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
    * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright 
      notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in 
      the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution

THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" 
AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE 
IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE 
ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE 
LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR 
CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF 
SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS 
INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN 
CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) 
ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE 
POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
```